# "Echoing" an image in Node.js

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, image, echo

I have a fully functioning PHP application that I am trying to make a Node.js version of. It deals with serving image tiles.  When it's ready to display the image it does:

```
// Stream out the image
echo self::$tile;
```

How would I do something similar in Node.js?  I understand this is a broad question, but I think my biggest issue is that I don't understand how PHP "echoes" an image.

---

## Details:

I'm using AWS to get the image.  The AWS call returns a Buffer.  At this point of time, in the Javascript I have left the image as a Buffer.

The site populates a map with tiled images, so there are multiple calls with the image placed at a particular location on the page.  I am using express to handle the requests.

```
app.get(/^\/omb\/1.0.0\/(.+)\/(.+)\/(.+)\/(.+)\.[a-zA-Z]*$/, function(req, res){
    var MosaicStreamer = require('./models/MosaicStreamer.js'); 
    var ms = new MosaicStreamer; 
    var configs = {library: req.params[0], zoom: req.params[1], column: req.params[2], row: req.params[3]}; 
    ms.handleTile(configs); 
});
```

`handleTile` grabs the image and ultimately brings me to where I am now. The image is grabbed using the following:

```
var aws = new AWS.S3(); 
var params = {
    Bucket: this.bucket,  
    Key: this.tileDirectory + this.filepath, 
    Range: 'bytes=' + (this.toffset + 4) + "-" + (this.tsize + this.toffset + 4)
};
var ts = this; 
aws.getObject(params, function(err, data){
    if(ts.tile == null){
       ts.tile = data.Body; //S3 get object 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see the code that created `self::$title`. Alternatively, can we see how `self::$title` is being used? Is it a base64 encoded image? Are you baking the result of it directly into the browser response and modifying headers, is this a BLOB? With these questions answered we can advise.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, okay I will do my best!  I'll edit the question

Comment: What PHP does when you use `echo` is write the output (in this case the binary contents) to the output buffer, which is connected via the web server to the browser requesting the resource. That same concept is done in node.js by writing the binary data to the "response stream" of the request. As there are a lot of ways you may have implemented the request handling, we need a tad more detail on what stack (e.g. express, api, the http module, etc) you are using, preferably with some example code.

Comment: @RogierSpieker added some details to the post. I'm using `express`.  So from what you're saying, I'm guessing I'm going to need to do something in the routing to handle the image?

Comment: Are you using an S3 bucket with your AWS instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is take a given URL which represents closely the naming convention of folders/files in your S3 Bucket. So assuming that you've established a client connection to your S3, you can use the `readFile` method. The 2nd argument is an `imageStream` which you can pass in the `response`. Once the stream has ended from S3, it will automatically end the `res` from the client, outputting the image directly to the client (as you intend).

Some psuedo code:

```
app.get(/^\/omb\/1.0.0\/(.+)\/(.+)\/(.+)\/(.+)\.[a-zA-Z]*$/, function(req, res){
    var MosaicStreamer = require('./models/MosaicStreamer.js'); 
    var ms = new MosaicStreamer; 
    var configs = {library: req.params[0], zoom: req.params[1], column: req.params[2], row: req.params[3]}; 
    return ms.handleTile(configs, res); 
    //return the handleTile function, add 2nd argument and pass res through
});
```

Inside of `handleTile` function you can make the call for the S3

```
function handleTile(configs, res){
    client.readFile('filename', function(error, imageStream){
        imageStream.pipe(res);
    });
}
```

Now requests to images like this:

```
<img src="/path/to/my/file/that/matches/regexp/expression"/>
```

It will request that image from the S3 Bucket and stream the resource back to the client directly.

Comment: I've been using the `aws-sdk` to make the get request.  

`var aws = new AWS.S3(); 

            var params = {
                Bucket: this.bucket,  
                Key: this.tileDirectory + this.filepath, 
                Range: 'bytes=' + (this.toffset + 4) + "-" + (this.tsize + this.toffset + 4)
            };
            var ts = this; 
             aws.getObject(params, function(err, data){
                 if(ts.tile == null){
                     ts.tile = data.Body; //S3 get object 
                 }}; `.  Would `client` assume I'm doing it another way? Is there another way?

Comment: @tibsar I used `client` but you used `aws` as your variable, no biggie. In this case, the 2nd argument to the function callback on `getObject()` is your stream, so you can pipe it directly to the response with `data.pipe(res)` inside of your express function.

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you're saying. Going to try it out.

Comment: turns out I'm still confused.  So you're saying do something along the lines of `aws.readFile(ts.tile, function(error, imageStream){ . . .`?

Comment: @tibsar You should be able to do `data.pipe(res)` inside of your `getObject` function, I think. Note that in this case, `getObject` and `readFile` shouldn't be used together as they serve a very similar purpose. They just accept different parameters.

Answer (score 0):

To successfully render an image, you have to implement three steps:

1. Retrieve the image data (for instance as a Buffer read via [`fs.readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readFile)) or a stream (for instance via [`fs.createReadStream`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options)
2. [Set](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value) the appropriate headers in the web request handler with the arguments `(req, res)`; something like

`res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/png'});`

3. [Write](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback) the file. If you have the file in a Buffer, with

   `res.end(buf, 'binary');`

   If you have a stream via

   `read_stream.pipe(res)`

The whole code may look like (assuming you want to serve the file `image.jpg` from the current directory):

```
'use strict';
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('image.jpg', function(err, buf) {
        if (err) {
            res.writeHead(500);
            res.end('Cannot access file.');
            return;
        }

        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'});
        res.end(buf, 'binary');
    });
}).listen(8002, '');
```

Using a stream, a very simple version (beware: no error handling, with error handling it can get a little bit more complex, depending how you want to handle errors occurring while the file is being read)

```
'use strict';
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var stream = fs.createReadStream('image.jpg');
    // Error handling omitted here
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'});
    stream.pipe(res);
}).listen(8003, '');
```

Code that uses a Buffer is easier to write, but means that your server must hold the whole file in memory - for instance, you will be unable to serve a [320 Gigapixel image](http://www.in2white.com/) file. You also only start sending data once you have the whole file.

Using a stream allows sending the file as soon as you get it, so it will be a little faster. If you're reading from file or a local fast server the speed difference is likely negligible. In addition, you'll only need a little bit of memory. On the other hand, error handling is more complex.

Comment: So my image is in a Buffer.  I need to read it before writing it?

Comment: Yes, that's step 1. I have added an example code that reads the file from filesystem. Of course, if your image source is not the filesystem but a database or remote server, the reading part (step 1) is going to look different.

Comment: What is the difference between using a stream and the other way?

Comment: So I tried it out, and it looks like it's getting to `http.createServer(function(req, res){`, but never going to `fs.readFile(ts.tile, function(err, data){`. It's just hanging and not throwing any error.  Any idea why it wouldn't go into the function?

Comment: @tibsar what is `ts.tile`? If that's not a path to an image directly on the file system, it's just going to dump and won't provide any errors given the psuedo code provided by OP.

Comment: `ts.tile` is the image. I'm pulling the image file from AWS, so `ts.tile` is the image as a Buffer

Comment: @tibsar Then the `buffer` should have an `imageStream`. Check my answer below.

Comment: @tibsar I have amended my answer with a discussion of stream vs buffer.

Comment: Looks like I'm still having the issue of getting into the function.  I changed my code to `http.createServer(function(req, res){
                        var stream = fs.createReadStream(ts.tile); 
                        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'}); 
                        stream.pipe(res); 
                         
                     }); `
but I seem to be unable to get into the function

Comment: @tibsar Which error do you get? (If you don't get any error, check that the code is executed in the first place, for example by placing `console.log` in it). Do you get any output inside the handling function? If `ts.tile` is already a Buffer object, you don't need `fs.createReadStream`; you've already completed step 1 then.

Comment: @phihag so I've tried a `console.log` and a breakpoint.  It appears that it gets to `http.createServer(function(req, res){` but will not go into the function at all.  And following if it doesn't seem to be outputting an error.

Comment: This means your requests are not coming in, and is unrelated to any image handling part of your question. Have you switched out 8003 for the HTTP port you are using? Is this port opened in your firewall? Do requests *from* the server (on the server with `curl http://localhost:8003/`) register?