# http.createServer never calling callback | Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, server

I'm working on a Node.js project and am attempting to use the `http` module.

Currently I have the following code:

```
http.createServer(function(req, res){
    console.log("here!!!!"); 
});
```

This never outputs to the console.  To test further, I placed a breakpoint on `console.log("here!!!!");`.  The breakpoint was never hit.  I then set a breakpoint on `http.createServer(function(req, res){`.  The program did stop at this breakpoint.  Stepping over showed that it then does not go into the callback but instead skips over it completely.

Any idea what would cause this?

---

## Details:

> app.js

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express(); 

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')

app.get('/map', function(req, res){
    res.render('view', {type: "block", name: req.query.name, latitude: req.query.latitude, longitude: req.query.longitude, zoom: req.query.zoom}); 
}); 

//Occurs when the picture is requested
app.get(/^\/omb\/1.0.0\/(.+)\/(.+)\/(.+)\/(.+)\.[a-zA-Z]*$/, function(req, res){
    var MosaicStreamer = require('./models/MosaicStreamer.js'); 
    var ms = new MosaicStreamer; 
    var configs = {library: req.params[0], zoom: req.params[1], column: req.params[2], row: req.params[3]}; 
    ms.handleTile(configs); 
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Tile Server listening on port 3000...'); 
});
```

Comment: Are you staring the server with the listen function? Are you makign a request to the server to see the console.log?

Comment: @tibsar How did you put breakpoint in JS file that is interpreted by NodeJS?

Comment: @user1655756 I've never used this module before.  So the callback is only called upon making a request to the server?

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski I'm using NetBeans

Comment: Check out this example 'Hello HTTP' https://howtonode.org/hello-node | Maybe you are missing some code or something.

Comment: @user1655756 Well this server isn't serving my entire application.  It's being used to place a picture to the screen

Comment: well, it still has to listen in some port and receive requests.

Comment: @user1655756 yes, but am I incorrect in thinking that the callback should be called upon the creation of the server?

Comment: The callback is called when you make a request to that server. When you create it, it's just listening there. Also, you miss the listen call. Check Krzysztof answer

Comment: @user1655756 I suppose what I'm not understanding is that I'm using an entirely different server for the application.  This is only to display a picture onto the screen. If I put the listen call, there is an issue because the port is already in use by the applications server. If I use a different port, it wouldn't be accessible, right?

Comment: You can use a different port and it will work. Or you can serve the image from the same server where your app is being served. Just use a different route.

Comment: @user1655756 I'm pretty new at this so I'm not entirely sure how to do this.  I'll show how my routing and server works in the question.

Comment: You need to back way up and describe what you're actually trying to accomplish.  You already have an Express server instance running.  You don't need another server instance just to serve an image.

Comment: @jfriend00 so basically I'm serving tiles. The tiles are images. There's multiple tiles on one page. The images are being requested with a GET request. The file is found using AWS, which is returned as a buffer object. I then need to get that buffer object to display to the screen. The reason I'm trying the server is because of responses to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37036819/echoing-an-image-in-node-js/37037024

Answer (score 0):

Let me copy & paste code from [NodeJS documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server) - you miss `.listen()` call.

```
'use strict';

const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  console.log(req)
  res.end();
});

server.listen(8000);
```

Comment: Well I have a different server serving this application.  This is being used simply to put a picture on the screen.  So would I still need a listen for that?

Comment: @tibsar without `listen()` on what port server works?